# When wil the new Thread() without reference be garbage collected

Tags: java, multithreading

In the below example, new Thread() doesnt have any reference. Is it possible that it be garbage collected below it is dead ?
Also without extending Thread class or implementing runnable, how are we creating a thread ?

```
public class TestFive {
    private int x;
    public void foo() {
            int current = x;
            x = current + 1;
    }
    public void go() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    new Thread() {
                            public void run() {
                                    foo();
                                    System.out.print(x + ", ");
                            } 
                    }.start();
            } 
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
            TestFive bb = new TestFive();
            bb.go();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A new thread that has not been started will be garbage collected when it becomes unreachable in the normal way.

A new thread that has been started becomes a garbage collection "root".  It won't be garbage collected until (after) it finishes.

> In the below example, new Thread() doesnt have any reference. Is it possible that it be garbage collected below it is dead ?

No.  It has been started, and hence won't be garbage collected until it finishes / dies.  And it *does* have a reachable reference until (at least) the point at which the `start()` call returns.

> Also without extending Thread class or implementing runnable, how are we creating a thread?

In your example, you *have* created anonymous subclass of `Thread`; i.e. a class that extends `Thread`.

Comment: also to his question on how the thread is created you should add that he actually does create a subclass of `Thread` albeit an anonymous subclass.

Comment: Also note that any threads that are running will also stop the JVM from shutting down.

Comment: if the start method is called by some other code after more than a month or two , will the Thread be garbage collected ?

Comment: @randeepsp, Time is not important. A second is about 3,000,000,000 clock cycles (i.e. an eternity) for a computer. It will behave the same after one year as it does after one second.

Answer (score 3):

No, a `Thread` which has been can't be garbage collected before the underlying VM thread (whether an OS-thread or not) has finished. I'm not sure offhand whether a `Thread` which doesn't have any obvious references to it but hasn't been `start()`-ed ends up causing a leak, or whether it can be collected - the latter, I'd expect.

As for your second question - your code *does* extend `Thread`, using an anonymous inner class, here:

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                foo();
                System.out.print(x + ", ");
        } 
}
```

I would personally suggest that even if you *did* want to use an anonymous inner class here, it's generally neater to implement `Runnable`:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        foo();
        System.out.print(x + ", ");
    } 
})
```

That way it's clear that you're *just* providing something to run, rather than trying to change any of the thread's core behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread will be available for garbage collection once it has finished running. The end of your `for` loop does not influence it, as the for loop runs in a different thread.

In answer to your second question, you **are** extending the Thread class by implementing your own `run()` function